# Does Outlook use the EWS api to send and receive emails?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

How does Outlook contact the exchange server to send and receive emails? Is it using EWS or POP, IMAP or some other technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Outlook does not use EWS.

But there's lots of protocols involved. Quoting from [Exchange Server Protocols System Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463895%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx):

> 2.1.3    Communications Within the System
>
> 2.1.3.1     Between an E-Mail Client and Exchange Servers
>
> Communication between an e-mail client and Exchange servers implements
>   SMTP or SMTP plus Exchange-specific extensions to SMTP, as described
>   in [MS-OXSMTP], for e-mail transmission.
>
> 2.1.3.2     Between a Messaging Client and Exchange Servers
>
> In the context of communication between a messaging client and
>   Exchange servers, "messaging client" refers to any generic client that
>   uses the Microsoft Exchange Server messaging system. A messaging
>   client does not necessarily have to be an e-mail client. As
>   illustrated in the figure in section 2.1, messaging clients have a
>   variety of protocol options to communicate with Exchange servers: RPC,
>   POP3, IMAP4, WebDAV, Web Services, NSPI, and Unified Messaging.

Since you're posting on StackExchange, it looks as if you (want to) do some Outlook/Exchange programming, and this is ony a prelude to your actual question?

Comment: Jan, Thanks for information, am using EWS to send and receive email in my application, but its very slow when compared to outlook while downloading and sending emails, is there any way i can improve va EWS??

Comment: @Spen Are you comparing with Outlook as an app, or with your code sending mail through OLE automation?. I only do calendar entries, but I notice no speed difference when my app uses EWS or Outlook OLE automation (late binding).

Comment: A correction to my previous remark: with certain customers we **do** see a speed difference between syncing directly through EWS SOAP calls or through OLE via Outlook. Maybe there is some caching/buffering mechanism at work between Outlook and Exchange, or its communication channel is just faster.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Outlook does use EWS when connected to Exchange for the functionality only available through EWS, such free/busy ranges with HTML replies, mail tips, etc.